# Good way to search through all Blender's options / actions?

Tags: settings

I'm trying to learn how to do simple things with Blender and am overwhelmed with complexity, and don't know of a good way to figure out basic things. I'd like to be able to search for some option / setting / action similar to how I can with other programs, eg. MS VS Code's settings menu [shows this when searching "font"](https://i.imgur.com/VOVkXHm.png).

I'm also struggling to figure things out because I don't know what keywords to search for, so I'd love something that caters to synonyms / fuzzy matching (eg. for the VS Code "font" eg show similar results when the user searches for "text" and finds few results).

Does Blender have such a feature, and if not, would the dev team please consider building one? You guys clearly do amazing stuff but it seems like such a steep learning curve for beginners is constraining your future growth. You could also collect stats on the most commonly searched things to figure out what to focus on.

Just an idea. Thanks for any help and thanks for building such awesome software.

Comment: Hi. YouTube has "countless" beginner, and how to set up Blender videos. Just use those terms in a search there. You should find something helpful. Be patient. As you mention it's "a steep learning curve for beginners". That's just the way it is.

Comment: Blender, and other 3D applications, are very wide-ranging, multi-functional. I would recommend, after getting a sketch overview, by, say, 'doing the doughnut', picking **one** area (out of Modelling, Materials, Rigging, Animation,  2D, Compositing, etc. etc.) and **forgetting** the others, while you build habits and muscle-memory in the specialism, starting from simple exercises, by following more focused series of tutorials. Nobody knows it all. Blender's grammar is quite consistent. One area will help you with the others, eventually, in the UI.

Comment: Also note that this Q&A site is run by volunteer Blender users. There are no developers here and no-one here has any association with the Blender Foundation. If you have any suggestions about changes to Blender you should start a thread on https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @curious_1 says in the comments, youtube is a great starting point if you want to learn Blender. I think a majority, if not all of the Blender users started there.

Anyway, Blender has a feature that allows you to search for commands by typing text :

[image: Search fommand]

You can access it by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.